# Expandable List View ignoring margin settings

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using the following layout files, which show the margins in place in the preview window.

EDIT: For the Java, I used the code here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#expandablelistview

MainActivity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
</ExpandableListView>
```

Group layout:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:layout_margin="7dp"
android:background="@color/heading_purple"

android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="15dp"

android:checkMark="@drawable/ic_action_expand"

android:text="Test"
android:textSize="15dp"
android:textColor="@color/light_text"
android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

List items layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/yes" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

However, as you can see from this image, the margins are being ignored and everything is right on top of each other:

[image]

Comment: Try padding instead of margin